# System Permissions Assigned to Permission Set

Tags: soql, community, governorlimits, sosl, dynamic-sosl

Is there a SOQL/SOSL to export/FETCH only the System Permissions from a Specific Permission Set in Salesforce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many fields available on permissionset object. You can query those permission which you need. In general:-

**PermissionsPermissionName**  One field for each permission. If true, users assigned to this permission set have the named permission. The number of fields varies depending on the permissions for the organization and license type.

read more here:- [PermissionSet](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272822/system-permissions-assigned-to-permission-set)

```
SELECT Id, Name, Label, LicenseId, ProfileId, IsOwnedByProfile, IsCustom, PermissionsEmailSingle, PermissionsEmailMass, PermissionsEditTask, PermissionsEditEvent, PermissionsExportReport, PermissionsImportPersonal, PermissionsDataExport, PermissionsManageUsers, PermissionsEditPublicFilters, PermissionsEditPublicTemplates, PermissionsModifyAllData, PermissionsManageCases, PermissionsMassInlineEdit, PermissionsEditKnowledge, PermissionsManageKnowledge, PermissionsManageSolutions, PermissionsCustomizeApplication, PermissionsEditReadonlyFields, PermissionsRunReports, PermissionsViewSetup, PermissionsTransferAnyEntity, PermissionsNewReportBuilder, PermissionsActivateContract, PermissionsActivateOrder, PermissionsImportLeads, PermissionsManageLeads, PermissionsTransferAnyLead, PermissionsViewAllData, PermissionsEditPublicDocuments, PermissionsViewEncryptedData, PermissionsEditBrandTemplates, PermissionsEditHtmlTemplates, PermissionsChatterInternalUser, PermissionsManageEncryptionKeys, PermissionsDeleteActivatedContract, PermissionsChatterInviteExternalUsers, PermissionsSendSitRequests, PermissionsOverrideForecasts, PermissionsViewAllForecasts, PermissionsApiUserOnly, PermissionsManageRemoteAccess, PermissionsCanUseNewDashboardBuilder, PermissionsManageCategories, PermissionsConvertLeads, PermissionsPasswordNeverExpires, PermissionsUseTeamReassignWizards, PermissionsEditActivatedOrders, PermissionsInstallPackaging, PermissionsPublishPackaging, PermissionsManagePartners, PermissionsChatterOwnGroups, PermissionsEditOppLineItemUnitPrice, PermissionsCreatePackaging, PermissionsBulkApiHardDelete, PermissionsInboundMigrationToolsUser, PermissionsSolutionImport, PermissionsManageCallCenters, PermissionsManageSynonyms, PermissionsOutboundMigrationToolsUser, PermissionsDelegatedPortalUserAdmin, PermissionsViewContent, PermissionsManageEmailClientConfig, PermissionsEnableNotifications, PermissionsManageDataIntegrations, PermissionsViewDataCategories, PermissionsManageDataCategories, PermissionsAuthorApex, PermissionsManageMobile, PermissionsApiEnabled, PermissionsManageCustomReportTypes, PermissionsManagePartnerNetConn, PermissionsEditCaseComments, PermissionsTransferAnyCase, PermissionsContentAdministrator, PermissionsCreateWorkspaces, PermissionsManageContentPermissions, PermissionsManageContentProperties, PermissionsManageContentTypes, PermissionsScheduleJob, PermissionsManageExchangeConfig, PermissionsManageAnalyticSnapshots, PermissionsScheduleReports, PermissionsManageBusinessHourHolidays, PermissionsManageDynamicDashboards, PermissionsManageInteraction, PermissionsViewMyTeamsDashboards, PermissionsModerateChatter, PermissionsResetPasswords, PermissionsFlowUFLRequired, PermissionsCanInsertFeedSystemFields, PermissionsActivitiesAccess, PermissionsManageKnowledgeImportExport, PermissionsEmailTemplateManagement, PermissionsEmailAdministration, PermissionsManageChatterMessages, PermissionsForceTwoFactor, PermissionsViewEventLogFiles, PermissionsManageNetworks, PermissionsViewCaseInteraction, PermissionsManageAuthProviders, PermissionsRunFlow, PermissionsViewGlobalHeader, PermissionsManageQuotas, PermissionsCreateCustomizeDashboards, PermissionsCreateDashboardFolders, PermissionsViewPublicDashboards, PermissionsManageDashbdsInPubFolders, PermissionsCreateCustomizeReports, PermissionsCreateReportFolders, PermissionsViewPublicReports, PermissionsManageReportsInPubFolders, PermissionsEditMyDashboards, PermissionsEditMyReports, PermissionsViewAllUsers, PermissionsAllowUniversalSearch, PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub, PermissionsCreateCustomizeFilters, PermissionsContentHubUser, PermissionsModerateNetworkFeeds, PermissionsModerateNetworkFiles, PermissionsGovernNetworks, PermissionsSalesConsole, PermissionsTwoFactorApi, PermissionsDeleteTopics, PermissionsEditTopics, PermissionsCreateTopics, PermissionsAssignTopics, PermissionsIdentityEnabled, PermissionsIdentityConnect, PermissionsAllowViewKnowledge, PermissionsContentWorkspaces, PermissionsCreateWorkBadgeDefinition, PermissionsManageSearchPromotionRules, PermissionsCustomMobileAppsAccess, PermissionsViewHelpLink, PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets, PermissionsAssignPermissionSets, PermissionsManageRoles, PermissionsManageIpAddresses, PermissionsManageSharing, PermissionsManageInternalUsers, PermissionsManagePasswordPolicies, PermissionsManageLoginAccessPolicies, PermissionsManageCustomPermissions, PermissionsCanVerifyComment, PermissionsManageUnlistedGroups, PermissionsStdAutomaticActivityCapture, PermissionsInsightsAppDashboardEditor, PermissionsManageTwoFactor, PermissionsInsightsAppUser, PermissionsInsightsAppAdmin, PermissionsInsightsAppEltEditor, PermissionsInsightsAppUploadUser, PermissionsInsightsCreateApplication, PermissionsDebugApex, PermissionsLightningExperienceUser, PermissionsConfigCustomRecs, PermissionsSubmitMacrosAllowed, PermissionsBulkMacrosAllowed, PermissionsShareInternalArticles, PermissionsModerateNetworkMessages, PermissionsManageSessionPermissionSets, PermissionsManageTemplatedApp, PermissionsUseTemplatedApp, PermissionsSendAnnouncementEmails, PermissionsChatterEditOwnPost, PermissionsChatterEditOwnRecordPost, PermissionsCreateAuditFields, PermissionsUpdateWithInactiveOwner, PermissionsWaveTrendReports, PermissionsWaveTabularDownload, PermissionsManageSandboxes, PermissionsAutomaticActivityCapture, PermissionsImportCustomObjects, PermissionsDelegatedTwoFactor, PermissionsChatterComposeUiCodesnippet, PermissionsSelectFilesFromSalesforce, PermissionsModerateNetworkUsers, PermissionsMergeTopics, PermissionsSubscribeToLightningReports, PermissionsManagePvtRptsAndDashbds, PermissionsAllowLightningLogin, PermissionsCampaignInfluence2, PermissionsViewDataAssessment, PermissionsRemoveDirectMessageMembers, PermissionsCanApproveFeedPost, PermissionsAddDirectMessageMembers, PermissionsAllowViewEditConvertedLeads, PermissionsFieldServiceAccess, PermissionsFieldServiceScheduling, PermissionsFieldServiceDispatcher, PermissionsFieldServiceMobileApp, PermissionsShowCompanyNameAsUserBadge, PermissionsAccessCMC, PermissionsOptOutGeoLocationTracking, PermissionsViewHealthCheck, PermissionsManageHealthCheck, PermissionsPackaging2, PermissionsManageCertificates, PermissionsCreateReportInLightning, PermissionsPreventClassicExperience, PermissionsHideReadByList, PermissionsUseSmartDataDiscovery, PermissionsGetSmartDataDiscovery, PermissionsCreateUpdateSDDDataset, PermissionsCreateUpdateSDDStory, PermissionsManageSmartDataDiscovery, PermissionsShareSmartDataDiscoveryStory, PermissionsManageSmartDataDiscoveryModel, PermissionsListEmailSend, PermissionsFeedPinning, PermissionsChangeDashboardColors, PermissionsManageRecommendationStrategies, PermissionsManagePropositions, PermissionsCloseConversations, PermissionsSubscribeReportRolesGrps, PermissionsSubscribeDashboardRolesGrps, PermissionsUseWebLink, PermissionsHasUnlimitedNBAExecutions, PermissionsViewOnlyEmbeddedAppUser, PermissionsAdoptionAnalyticsUser, PermissionsViewAllActivities, PermissionsSubscribeReportToOtherUsers, PermissionsLightningConsoleAllowedForUser, PermissionsSubscribeReportsRunAsUser, PermissionsSubscribeToLightningDashboards, PermissionsSubscribeDashboardToOtherUsers, PermissionsCreateLtngTempInPub, PermissionsTransactionalEmailSend, PermissionsViewPrivateStaticResources, PermissionsViewCustomerSentiment, PermissionsCreateLtngTempFolder, PermissionsApexRestServices, PermissionsEnableCommunityAppLauncher, PermissionsGiveRecognitionBadge, PermissionsCanRunAnalysis, PermissionsCanEditAnalysis, PermissionsLtngPromoReserved01UserPerm, PermissionsManageSubscriptions, PermissionsWaveManagePrivateAssetsUser, PermissionsCanEditDataPrepRecipe, PermissionsAddAnalyticsRemoteConnections, PermissionsManageSurveys, PermissionsRecordVisibilityAPI, PermissionsViewRoles, PermissionsEinsteinAssistantUser, PermissionsSmartDataDiscoveryForCommunity, PermissionsCanManageMaps, PermissionsStoryOnDSWithPredicate, PermissionsModifyDataClassification, PermissionsPrivacyDataAccess, PermissionsQueryAllFiles, PermissionsModifyMetadata, PermissionsCreateContentSpace, PermissionsSandboxTestingInCommunityApp, PermissionsViewFlowUsageAndFlowEventData, PermissionsCanEditPrompts, PermissionsViewUserPII, Description, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, NamespacePrefix, HasActivationRequired, Type FROM PermissionSet
```